# eth_call to a constant field in contract returns "0x" on Rinkeby

Tags: rinkeby, raiden

I'm trying out Micro Raiden on Rinkeby testnet, but a call to 'token' field in a contract returns empty value (0x) when using infura.io directly or geth, but not on MEW connected to infura.io.

This fails: (I checked that 0xfc0c546a is correctly a hash of 'token()')

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "eth_call",
    "params": [
        {
            "data": "0xfc0c546a",
            "to": "0x568a0d52a173f584d4a286a22b2a876911079e15"
        },
        "latest"
    ],
    "id": 1
}
```

returns:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "result": "0x"
}
```

But MEW connected to rinkeby via infura works as intended:

[image]

What could be wrong in the raw request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce the issue. Here's the request I made, which appears to be working properly:

```
$ curl -X POST https://rinkeby.infura.io/<MY TOKEN REDACTED> -d '{"id": 1, "jsonprc": "2.0", "method": "eth_call", "params": [{"data": "0xfc0c546a", "to": "0x568a0d52a173f584d4a286a22b2a876911079e15"}, "latest"]}'

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x000000000000000000000000101e64900a7f283468ec7484691afca8385dc1d8"}
```

If things still aren't working for you, can you please share the exact HTTP request you're making?

Comment: Thanks, it's indeed working. I found that microraiden was using localhost for some requests even with the main Web3 object pointing to infura. So it was hitting my no-yet-synced geth.